# Expected argument of type "string", "AclBundle\Entity\Image" given

Tags: php, symfony

**I get this error from adding a ImageType to the user Form , i'm using FOSUserBundle for User Entity ! ANY HELP**

this my User Entity

```
<?php

namespace AclBundle\Entity;

use AclBundle\Entity\Image;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ab_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AclBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cin", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $cin;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="birthdate", type="date")
     */
    private $birthdate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the picture as a image file.")
     * @Assert\Image(mimeTypes={ "image/jpeg" })
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
     *
     */
    private $photo;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateSubscribe", type="date", length=255)
     */
    private $dateInscription;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="json_array")
     */
    private $role = [];



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set cin
     *
     * @param string $cin
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setCin($cin)
    {
        $this->cin = $cin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cin
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCin()
    {
        return $this->cin;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstname
     *
     * @param string $firstname
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastname
     *
     * @param string $lastname
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Set birthdate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $birthdate
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setBirthdate($birthdate)
    {
        $this->birthdate = $birthdate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get birthdate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getBirthdate()
    {
        return $this->birthdate;
    }



    /**
     * Set phone
     *
     * @param string $phone
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phone
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $role
     * @return string
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        if(in_array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', $this->role)) $role = 'Super Administrator';
        else if(in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $this->role)) $role = 'Administrator';
        else if(in_array('ROLE_MANAGER', $this->role)) $role = 'Manager';
        else if(in_array('ROLE_ASSOCIATION', $this->role)) $role = 'Association';
        else if(in_array('ROLE_USER', $this->role)) $role = 'Member';
        return $role;


    }
    /**
     * Get photo
     *
     * @return \AclBundle\Entity\Image
     */
    public function getPhoto()
    {
        return $this->photo;
    }

    /**
     * @param \AclBundle\Entity\Image $photo
     *
     * @return User
     *
     */
    public function setPhoto(\AclBundle\Entity\Image $photo = null)
    {
        $this->photo = $photo;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateInscription()
    {
        return $this->dateInscription;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $dateInscription
     */
    public function setDateInscription($dateInscription)
    {
        $this->dateInscription = $dateInscription;
    }



    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->dateInscription = new \DateTime('NOW');
    }
}
```

and My RegistrationType looks like

```
    <?php

namespace AclBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('cin',TextType::class)
            ->add('firstname',TextType::class)
            ->add('lastname',TextType::class)
            ->add('birthdate',DateType::class,[
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control input-inline date',
                        'data-provide' => 'datepicker',
                        'data-date-format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy'
                    ],
                    'html5' => false,
                ]
            )
            ->add('phone',TextType::class)
            ->add('photo',ImageType::class, array('required' => false));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

}
```

My ImageType is :

```
<?php

namespace AclBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

            ->add('file',FileType::class);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AclBundle\Entity\Image'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'aclbundle_image';
    }


}
```

I tried a lot of suggested solution but it didn't work for my case ! , i think it is a simple error but my mind is blowed up

Comment: Need to add a use statement for ImageType.

Comment: i add the use statement but it doesn't worked !

Comment: can you show us your ImageType code?

Comment: @goto i edit the question and i add the code of the ImageType